# Wi-fi signal with keeping the internet cable

Tags: router, lan, internet, wireless-networking, cable

So the situation is that I have Ethernet cable which provides internet to my computer. Thing I want is to have wi-fi connection in my house and Ethernet cable (like I have before) to use for my PC. I will use wi-fi for my laptop and mobile phone. I think I need router for that and I'm looking at Asus RT-N16 ([suggested in Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/06/because-everyone-still-needs-a-router.html)) for it, but I am not sure. Is it the right thing for me and I will be able to get wi-fi signal and keep the Ethernet cable? I guess the system will be that current cable goes into router, router provides wi-fi signal and gives back new cable... or something like that.

Thanks in any advice! And sorry if topic isn't in right site.

Comment: You probably want move this post to superuser and add a few more details. E.g. what is 'an internet cable'. Can I carry that with me to the beach?  (Sorry for the sarcasm, but I think the point is clear).

Comment: I install wireless systems for a living.  I don't want to go anywhere near this question until it gets revised a bit.

Comment: It would really help to know what "internet cable" means. Is that an Ethernet line coming from a cable modem? Or what?

Comment: It's Ethernet, yes. Sorry for my bad understanding, but that is why I ask.

Comment: What OS is this? And you need more details.

Comment: My computer which should receive cable from router has Arch Linux on it and devices which should be able to connect to wi-fi have Windows and Android. What else do you need to know? I have no problems with answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Asus has one upstream and  four downstream Ethernet ports. (Standard features for home wireless routers.) You can connect your router to your existing connection, then connect your PC to your router. You'll need to configure your router to use the network provided by your existing Internet connection. (Without knowing more about how that connection works, I can't give you specifics.) You may also need to reconfigure your PC. The simplest setup is to have the PC get its network parameters from the router.

Answer (score 2):

Most wireless router have four downstream ports - You can use an ethernet cable to connect your computer with the router and also the laptop and mobile can connect over wireless from the same router. The router you've mentioned seems like a WAN router and since there are different sorts of connections types across regions, I would not be in a position to answer if you can use that or not. I would recommend you to speak with your ISP and find our your connection type and also which router they could recommend to you :)